# Error using Retrofit with OkHttp for calling REST service

Tags: android, web-services, http-get, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for calling REST web API (a GET request).

The RestAdapter is:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(strEndpoint)
    .build();
```

and this works fine.

Sometimes, however, the http GET is a bit slow, so the Callback that I have implemented in the `failure(RetrofitError err)` returns a error, like:

```
10-02 16:47:15.279: I/ERROR(16413): error downloading data: failed to connect to myserver.privete.com (port 80) after 15000ms
```

However, this error appens only if I use wifi connection.

So I have decide to try changing the connection timeout, adding a custom OkClient, using the library [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
client.setReadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(Parameters.production ? Parameters.productionEndPoint : Parameters.testEndPoint)
    .setClient(new OkClient(client))
    .build();
```

But this generates IMMEDIATELY this error:

```
10-02 16:42:38.489: I/ERROR(14259): error downloading data: com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient.open
```

I versions I used are shown below:

```
Retrofit: 1.6.1 
okhttp: 2.0.0 
okhttp-urlconnection: 1.6.0
```

EDIT:

I also tried with okhttp-urlconnection 2.0.0

Comment: Are you sure that myserver.private.com is on the same network of the mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need okhttp-urlconnection 2.0.0.

Unrelated to this, but for any future problems you can get better debug output by using

```
    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
```

Comment: I also tried using the 2.0.0 version of okhttp-urlconnection.